# Computing $\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{n!}{i!} \mod p$

Tags: summation, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the fastest way to compute $$\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{n!}{i!} \mod p$$ where one can suppose that $p$ is a prime number.

Given that $n$ can be a huge number, the only simple way I can think of now is a $O(n)$ algorithm. Can we do better than that ?

Note that $u_n=\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{n!}{i!} = \lfloor n!e \rfloor$ for $n >0$ and that $u_{n+1} = n(u_n+1)$, if that helps.

Comment: You can have the sum start at $i=n-p+1$, since all other terms are individually $0$ mod $p$. In fact, if $n=r\bmod p$ with $r\geq 0$ minimal, you can have the sum start at $i=n-r$.

Comment: If $p$ stays small, you can do it fairly quickly.  For example, if $n=1000$ and $p=7$, you get $$1+1000(1+999(1+998(1+997(1+996(1+995(1+0))))))\\\equiv1+6(1+5(1+4(1+3(1+2(1+1)))))\equiv\cdots$$ since $7\mid994$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, $p$ here is usually a large prime number, like $10^9+7$.